# how to implement CRUD using jquery datatable in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5.3

i am using data-table plugins in my Laravel 5.3 project i can show my all data but can't implement edit and delete how implement that.

```
<script>
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').DataTable({
        processing : true,
        serverSide : true,
        ajax       : '{{URL::asset('data')}}',
        columns    :[
            {data:'id',name:'id'},
            {data:'prizebond_number',name:'prizebond_number'},
            {data:'prizebond_location',name:'prizebond_location'},

            {
                mRender: function (data, type, row) {
                    var linkEdit='<a href="{{url('user_prizebonds.edit')}}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="' + row['id'] + '">EDIT</a>';
                    var linkDelete='<a href="{{url('user_prizebonds.destroy')}}" class="editor_remove btn btn-danger btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-trash" data-id="' + row["data:id"] + '">DELETE</a>';
                    return  linkEdit + "  " + linkDelete;
                }
            }

        ]
    });
} );
```

//mycontroller code

```
public function data(){
    $current_user_id=Auth::id();
    $user_prizebonds=UserPrizebond::where('user_id', "$current_user_id")->get();
   return Datatables::of($user_prizebonds)->make(true);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write into your controller function. like this

```
return Datatables::of($user_prizebonds)->addColumn('action', function ($user_prizebonds) {
    return = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>';
})->make(true);
```

and js code

```
{data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
```